# Regular Expression for BBcode replacement

Tags: regex, bbcode

I need PCRE regex for replace

```html
This
[quote author=MEMBER link=topic=8.msg1111 date=1438798587]
sample text[/quote]

To this one
[quote="MEMBER, post: 1111"]sample text[/quote]
```

So i need:

- Delete attribute `date=xxxxxxxxxx` and place `"` in end of tag (after post id)
- Replace `link=topic=8.msg` to `post:`
- Replace `author=` to `="`

Can sombody help please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can try this :

```
\[quote\sauthor=([^\s]+)\s*.*?msg(\d+)\s[^]]*]\s*([^[]*)(\[\/quote])
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sIiuyL/1/).

Although I can't be sure this is really standard to your kind of inputs since you only provided one sample.

Comment: Thanks! Its work, but when i use it, it takes only first letter of "MEMBER" like this: `[quote="A, post: 1936"] ` instead of `[quote="Ares, post: 1936"] `

Comment: fixed using double +: `\[quote\sauthor=([^\s]++)\s*.*?msg(\d+)\s[^]]*]\s*([^[]*)(\[\/quote])`